# PostgreSQL/Java Shopping Cart ArrayList Printing Empty List

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, arraylist

I am having issues with printing out my shopping cart in a different function from which the item is added to the cart.The shopping cart is an ArrayList of Book type. My program is a Menu implementation which allows the user to choose different options(option 1,2, etc..) to search for books by, i.e. ISBN, author, etc. There is also another option in which the user selects that displays the shopping cart and eventually remove entries from the cart. My issue is that when I try to call the `displayShoppingCart()` function in `option5()` function I receive an empty array. However, when I call `displayShoppingCart()` in the `option1()` function the cart properly displays. I have included the code from `option1()`, `option5()`, and `displayShoppingCart()` Any help or feedback is greatly appreciated!

```
List<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<>();
List <Book> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<>();

public void option1() throws SQLException, IOException {
      // attempts to connect to the database
      jdbc = new DBConnection();
      connection = jdbc.getConnection();
      // sql statements are here - this works properly 
      // all of the following code is located in each option function
      System.out.println("Book added to cart successfully!");
      Book cart = new BookSale().new Book();
      cart = booklist.get(option); // option is the selection of book user chooses to add to cart
      cart.getSeller();
      cart.getIsbn();
      cart.getprice();
      shoppingCart.add(cart);
      displayShoppingCart(shoppingCart); // this prints out the cart correctly
}

public void option5() throws SQLException, IOException {

     // display current shopping cart of member
     System.out.println("Your current shopping cart: ");
     *displayShoppingCart(shoppingCart); // prints out empty array*
}

// function to print shoppingCart
public void displayShoppingCart(List <Book> shoppingCart) {
      System.out.println(shoppingCart.toString());
      }
```

Comment: In the `option5` method you create a new (empty) list and print it out.  It *should* be empty.  Perhaps you meant to use the existing `shoppingCart` variable?

Comment: @stdunbar Yes, that is what I tried to do. However, when I try to use the existing shoppingCart variable I receive an error

Comment: My ability to read minds doesn't work very well on Mondays.  Perhaps you could show the error information by editing your post and including it?

Comment: @stdunbar I'm sorry I didn't mean to put an "error" as in an error message. I receive an error in regards to the list still prints empty

Comment: Ok, then I'm still confused as to what the issue is.  In `option1` you add one or more `Book` objects to the `shoppingCart` and the objects are there.  In `option5` you create a **brand new empty** `List` and never add anything to it nor into the `shoppingCart` List.  Something is missing from the problem statement as the code you show will produce exactly what you're describing.

Comment: @stdunbar I have taken out adding a brand new empty list.  I am trying to reference the shoppingCart in the various options function(option1() function) to print out. However, when I try to print the shoppingCart in option5 a blank array is printed

Comment: Did you put anything into `shoppingCart` or did you call `option1` first?  You're not putting anything into the `List` in your current code.

Comment: @stdunbar I call option1 first and select book to put into the shopping cart.

Comment: Without a [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'm spinning my wheels.  Post code that show the problem.

Comment: @stdunbar I have posted the code the causes the problem.It is when I call the displayShoppingCart() in option5 and an empty list is returned. However, I am trying to print the shoppingCart referenced in all of the options